# Which documents do you have to produce when entering India on a multi-entry business visa?

Tags: visas, india, business-travel

I have a multiple-entry business visa. I have entered once previously, and next month will be my second visit. Will I be required to show a new invitation letter and employer cover letter, the originals that I used to apply for the visa? Or is simply the visa in the passport enough?

I can't remember if I had to show the original documents on my first visit. My employer sponsor is the same, but the company that I will be visiting is different from the original invitation I received and used to apply for the visa.

Answer (score 1):

Once granted for multiple entries, the [Government of India Bureau of Immigration](https://boi.gov.in/content/business-visa-b) places no added documentary requirements or obligations for future visits:

> Business visa are given with the multiple-entry option so person can visit as many time within the validity of the visa.

On a business-related trip on behalf of the same company as in your visa application, your visa is sufficient. Upon arrival, at Immigration, you are likely to be asked the purpose of your visit, business, but not whether it’s to the same company as on your previous trip. You would have with you, of course, contacts, paperwork, and arrangements related to company you’ll be seeing; that should be more than enough, should it come up.